# jQuery Uniform dropdown not selecting option

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-plugins, drop-down-menu

I am using a pretty basic and straightforward implementation of jQuery Uniform on a couple of dropdowns.

When the page loads, the dropdowns are skinned correctly by the plugin.

However, when I select an option and submit the form, I can see that no data is being posted.

If I remove the plugin then my form submits correctly with the selected option being passed OK.

Any ideas how to trouble shoot this?

Comment: does plugin `wrap()` the option tags?

Comment: not sure if I understand - the plugin definitely wraps the <select> tags with a <div class="selector">

Comment: in most cases after wrapping the form elements, browser does not send the form's data.

Comment: I use this plugin in other projects and it works fine... just can't figure out why it's breaking this particular one

Comment: i think markup is the culprit.

Comment: raminson thx for the insight - `<form>` was **inside** the `<table>`... aaaargh... now it works